# When to use a runabout or a shuttle in a mission?

Tags: star-trek

In TNG and DS9, we often see the use of shuttles and runabouts. What is the deciding factor of which one to use? How come we only see one use of a runabout in TNG? Is it only about the crew size on board? Yet shuttles have been shown to carry quite a number of people too? Is it speed?

Comment: Captain Picard looks at the script and does a quick calculation to work out how much airtime he needs to fill and whether there's a need for two or more crewmembers to learn to grudgingly respect each other. Then he decides.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The difference between a runabout and a shuttlecraft is a matter of size and capability. Most of the time, their duties were interchangeable so either ship could be used. With the ability to customize ships in the Federation, there are numerous designs for shuttlecraft which includes vehicles such as the [Delta Flyer](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Delta_Flyer) (VOY) or the [Captain's Yacht, Cousteau](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Captain%27s_yacht) (TNG).**

- Shuttlecraft were small ships assigned to starships, used primarily in cargo transportation, short trips for species which experience transporter difficulties or anxiety, or movement through electromagnetic phenomenon which might disrupt or challenge transporter technologies.
- Shuttlecraft had to be fit during the TOS period with technologies to allow them to be used with warp drives. By the TNG series, shuttlecraft came standard with relatively short-hop warp capacities (some light years allowing them to be used as exploration vehicles). There were [many different classes of shuttlecraft](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/schematics/starfleet_shuttles.htm) depending on the duties being carried out.
- Runabouts were slightly larger than shuttlecraft but smaller than starships. Runabouts were warp-capable, had personal transporters and usually had a crew of four personnel. Properly fitted, they could function as transports, scientific vehicles or medical evacuation vehicles. Runabouts were used primarily on space stations such as Deep Space Nine (DS9) as a means of travel between the Federation, Cardassian and Bajoran sectors of space.

[image]

Runabout specifications included deflectors and phaser arrays. But they were not meant to sustain much damage, despite the fact they could be used in combat.

[image]

Comment: I should totally steal your graphic for my answer :)

Comment: I think the writers don't realize how small some of those shuttles are. The work bee is 2/3 the size of a geo metro. If the passenger compartment were the same as a smart car (looking at the angle that's a very generous estimate), they'd have a bit over a meter in which to fit the engines, electronics, heat shielding, fuel tank, etc.

Comment: The very tiny ones are likely very limited in their capacities. I can see them being used in shipyards to move around a starship for work on the frame or on hull repairs in space. I doubt serious if the tiny ones have a drive capable of doing much more than staying close to the ship using reaction thrusters.

Comment: Basically a space car/truck vs a space RV.

Answer (score 8):

Shuttlecraft are short range craft used on starships and space stations to ferry people from place to place where the transporter is either a poor or impossible choice. It also allows for personnel to move around without tasking an entire starship to accompany them, such as when crew members have a transfer or family emergency. They have limited warp and are mainly intended to stay close to their mothership. Think of them as the lighters that old style sailing vessels had. Good for short trips or just two for a long one. They are also barely armed, often with just a phaser array and no photon torpedoes.

Runabouts, on the other hand, are designed to be much more hardy. They can sustain Warp 5, pack a couple of phaser arrays and occasionally stock a couple of torpedoes. They are intended to operate on their own for extended missions and are employed mainly on spacestations. They can hold quite a number of people on short or extended trips. They are also larger in length than the shuttles.

We see shuttles mainly in the Next Gen, used for dignitary transport, crew swaps and a few detached missions.

The runabouts were used a lot during Deep Space Nine where they were used in Dominion space and quite frequently in combat.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what has been said, runabouts are modular and can be refited for different functions.  They can be used for cargo with the center refited with a cargo hold or fitted with a lounge and crew cabins like in tng, they can also be fitted with a larger phaser aray or torpedo somewhat like other modular star fleet ships.

Shuttles and shuttle craft are more like work vehicles for missions and transport but even later shuttles start to take on a more runabout/delta flyer like style with larger size and better weapons they are just in the movies or alt futures.

Answer (score -3):

Very nice web.

To add,now i watching VOY & DS9 in parallel by stardates & noticed Runabouts r much less fragile compared with over 50% VOY shuttles lost by hard landing,if U c a shuttle about to land in VOY,u may be sure,there is over 50% probability of fatal landing,it is quite illogical to have such fragile shuttles,every 2nd atmosphere disables them & render to crash.Runabouts seems to be safer for landing,mainly if U dislike to stay stacked on a planet,instead of an irreversible shuttle crash landing tradition in VOY & TNG,the DS9 tradition is losing runabouts in combat,in fact shuttles in TNG & VOY & runabouts in DS9 plays the role of red shirts in TOS.

About the specs:Runabouts has clear specs about warp max.sust.5,capacity,modularity,weapons etc,but specs of shuttles vary web by web & even episode by episode,for example the top speed of type 9 shuttle,i found various sources stating some only warp 4,another sources even warp 7,same differences in episodes,for example in that episode,where Janeway & Chakotay r left behind on a planet because of infection Paris states,type 9 shuttle has top speed warp 4,but in Treshhold type 9 shuttle switches from its standard drive to that enhanced added by Paris @ speed of warp 7(up to warp 7 the speed is reached by original drive components,u can hear it stated-the switching to added warp 10 drive),thus not easy to decide by speed,but other parameters r,as there was stated,but 1 more difference is,runabouts r considered independent ships,they has their own registry unlike shuttles sharing registry of their mothership or base & about choosing for a mission...u have mostly no choice,as most starships has no runabouts onboard,but most starships has captain´s yacht,so on a starship u will mostly choose by away mission range,capacity & equipment needed between a shuttle & yacht,the choice between a shuttle & runabout is mostly available on stations,but stations has mostly no type 9 or 11 shuttles,thus u will take runabout even for shorter missions.

Ships of about a runabout size was also seen as private vessels,the most famous such private vessel is Raven...interesting question is,how a non-starfleet UFP citizen can obtain a ship(money does not exist in UFP,so when u have choosen & demand a shuttle or a runabout,u cannot buy it,so a fleetyard will give it to u?)...or even a drink in Quark´s,i always wonder,how a Federation citizen can pay a drink,when they have no payments...only way seems to be a replicating of the currency for the bar...for the ship/shuttle...industrial replicator?

Thanx 4 good web & for this article,for the most precious comparison of auxiliary craft(even runabouts r officially not auxiliary craft-the other huge difference) & for that nice specs picture of Ganges.
in fact i was searching for preciously that,i am glad,i found it,u ware very useful to me.

Comment: Please use paragraphs to space your text apart more in future. A solid wall of text is needlessly difficult to read though. Also, please don't use answers to respond to other user's answers. That's what the [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) function is for. You don't have access to it yet, but you will if you earn a bit more [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Writing in txt spk makes it hard for people to read your answers. U shd try 2 wrt in propr Eng.